# Automatically clicking 500+ links on a website

Tags: javascript, python, automation

I've requested my data from a popular social media app. There are photos they have saved and have provided download links to. I don't want to click each one individually.

What's the best option of automatically going down the entire page and "click" each download link? Python? JS?

Thanks.

Comment: explore selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium or Puppeteer.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer
https://www.selenium.dev/

Both tools are great to automate task like this.
You may also want to read this book on automating with python:
https://automatetheboringstuff.com/

Comment: Thank you. It's able to open the site and download the first file. How would you recommend looping it so it finds the next item to download? Would it make sense to try to edit the HTML to remove the original download when it's finished so the next download will be at the top of the list? Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Try this: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/ It will get you started and at least understand the code behind it.